# Restrictions on PHP include()

Tags: php, xhtml, include, restriction

I am separating some XHTML from PHP by putting the XHTML into a separate file and then using PHP's `include()` function within the PHP script.

This works perfectly fine, however, users are still able to access the `.html` file directly if they know the address. They can't really do much with it, but I would rather it not show.

I've seen some scripts in the past use some form of referrer check, is this what I would do to add some basic (*Notice I said 'basic'*) restrictions to prevent it from being viewed by accessing it directly?

Thanks!

**Clarification**: I forgot to mention that I want to do this within PHP, so no web-server configuration (*Moving files out of document-root, configuring web-server to disallow access, etc.*). I think the most logical choice here is to use the `define()` constant check, that's actually indeed what I've seen in other scripts that I had forgotten, as I outlined in my post. I realize this is probably not the best solution, but given that the html file that can be access is of no particular value, the `define()` constant should suffice.

Comment: I just saw the "Thanks I appreciate the responses!" and thought "This guys isn't going to accept an answer", as most newbies do. I checked out your profile and realized you weren't a newbie, but kept the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you currently place all your files (like index.php) in `/something/public_html/` you will want to move the files to `/something/`. That way users cannot access the files.

The `/public_html/` is called your document root. That folder is mapped to `example.com`, and and basically the website starts there. If you move the files to above where the website starts, no one can access those files via a browser.

As Ignacio said, this will not work with `include` if safe mode is turned on.

Other methods are to place something at the top of the file thats says

```
if(!defined("RUNNING_SCRIPT"))
    die("No Direct Access Allowed");
```

and then in your PHP files put

```
 define("RUNNING_SCRIPT", true);
```

If `RUNNING_SCRIPT` is not defined, that means they are directly accessing it, and it stops the page from loading. This only works though if PHP runs on the `.html` files.

You could also use a `.htaccess` file to disallowed access to that folders.

Comment: By "PHP runs on the .html files", the html file outputs certain strings using php's echo, would that constitute as 'php runnin on the html file'?

Comment: Unless you have modified the server, PHP only runs on `.php` files, or files included by PHP. It is simple, put `<?php echo "Test"; ?>` in the `.html` file and see if it runs when you access it directly, or if you just get the PHP code.

Comment: Some people create a `.htaccess` file to make PHP run on `.html` files, and sometimes the system admin will put it into the PHP configuration. But, if PHP doesn't run on the file, you can't use PHP to protected it.

Comment: Actually, I almost completely missed this. I could just make the `.html` file `.php` and include that `define` constant check at the top, right?

Comment: Including `.html` files is not, by any means a bad practice. But, if you plan on using PHP code inside of them, you might want to just rename them to `.php` files instead, and use the `define` solution to stop people from accessing them.

Comment: Correct, you could just rename the files :)

Comment: Generally I name all of the files that contain php to end in `.php`, as I might use them incorrectly otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Just move it outside of the document root. This will not work if PHP is in Safe Mode though.

Answer (score 3):

Change your webserver configuration to disallow access to that file?

Answer (score 3):

No, do something like this:

**index.php:**

```
<?php

define('ALLOW_INCLUDE', true);

include('other.php');

?>
```

**other.php:**

```
<?php

if (defined('ALLOW_INCLUDE') === false) die('no direct access!');

// your code

?>
```

Comment: Remember, this won't work if the files are not parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to place this as the first line.

You can also use .htaccess or drop a index.html page too as fallbacks.

```
<?php defined('SOME_CONSTANT_GLOBAL_TO_YOUR_APP') or die('Access denied.'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be apache access control?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html